# onchange dynamic dropdown values using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have written a code for two dropdown boxes. The first dropdown contains a list of main category dynamic values. when i select any one of the value in main category list the second dropdown should appear with corresponding sub category values. How can i do this?
Here is my code:

```
            <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                                <div class="form-group">
                        Please Choose Your Category
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                         <select class="form-control" name="category_name" onchange="mainInfo(this.value);">
                                            <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
                                            <option value="Birds">Birds</option>
                                                <option value="Animals">Animals</option>
                                            <option value="Notinlist">Category Not in list</option>
                                         </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                                <div class="form-group">
                        Please Choose Your Sub Category
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                         <select class="form-control" name="album_name">
                                            <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
                                            <option value="Birds">Sub Birds</option>
                                                <option value="Animals">Sub Animals</option>
                                            <option value="Notinlist">Category Not in list</option>
                                         </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>
```

php code to fetch sub category for main category

```
 <?php 
 $album_category = $_POST['category_name'];
 $sql=$conn->prepare("select * from `albums` where album_category=:album_category");
 $sql->bindParam(":album_category",$album_category);
 $sql->execute();
 while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
  echo $row['album_sub_category'];
```

}
        ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Change your code to something like that :*

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
       <div class="form-group">
       Please Choose Your Category
       </div>
    </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="form-group">
       <select class="form-control" name="category_name" id="category_name" onchange="mainInfo(this.value);">
            <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
            <option value="Birds">Birds</option>
            <option value="Animals">Animals</option>
            <option value="Notinlist">Category Not in list</option>
         </select>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="form-group">
         Please Choose Your Sub Category
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="form-group">
         <select class="form-control" name="album_name" id="album_name">
            <option value="">Please Select</option>
          </select>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

**Add this ajax function :**

```
<script>
function mainInfo(str)
{
    var n;
    if (str=="0")
    {
        document.getElementById("album_name").innerHTML="<option>--Select --</option>";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        n=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        n=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    n.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (n.readyState==4 && n.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("album_name").innerHTML=n.responseText;
    }
    }

    n.open("GET","sub_category.php&category_name="+str,true);
    n.send();
}
</script>
```

**And on the php page which is *sub_category.php***

```
<?php 
 $album_category = $_POST['category_name'];
 $sql=$conn->prepare("select * from `albums` where album_category=album_category");
 $sql->bindParam(":album_category",$album_category);
 $sql->execute();?>
<option value="">--Select State--</option>
<?php
 while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['album_sub_category'];?>"><?php echo  $row['album_sub_category'];?></option>
   <?php
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the items in the list are small enough preload load into the page, you're going to have to make an http endpoint for fetching the raw data using AJAX and then draw it on the client with JavaScript. jQuery would make light work of it.

The other option would involve reloading the page for each change... Yuck...

You're client code could be something like this with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({url: '/categories.json', data: {cat:'category name'}}).done(function(cats){
    $.each(cats, function(){
        $('#Target').append($('<option>', {value:this}).text(this));
    })
}).fail(function(){
    // Handle error
});
```

Since no method id specified it will default to `GET` and the `data` object will be converted to `GET` variables which you can use for the DB query to get the applicable sub categories and return them in JSON with proper JSON headers.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  how is my categories.json file looks like? What should i do in that?