# PHP Form with MySql Database

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I need some help to create an form from database:[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvpzW.png)

And I have this:

```
global $wpdb;
//$query ="SELECT modelo,ID FROM volumes"; 
$query ="SELECT Modelo,ID FROM volumes order by ID";
$wpdb->query($query)
```

**And this:**

```
<div class="form_fields">
<p>
<label for="modelo">Model:
echo "<select name=Modelo value=''>Modelo</option>"; // list box select command

foreach ($wpdb->query($query) as $row){//Array or records stored in $row

echo "<option value=$row[ID]>$row[Modelo]</option>"; 

/* Option values are added by looping through the array */ 

}

 echo "</select>";// Closing of list box
        </label>
    </p></div>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Your code is a little bit messy, it's hard to see what is wrong with the code now.

Comment: You never need a global variable if you code **object oriented**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this :

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$query ="SELECT Modelo,ID FROM volumes order by ID";
$wpdb->query($query);
?>

<div class="form_fields">
  <label for="modelo">Model: </label>
    <select name=Modelo value=''>
      <option>Modelo</option>
         <?php
         foreach ($wpdb->query($query) as $row) {
          ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row->ID; ?>"><?php echo $row->Modelo; ?></option>
         <?php
         }
            ?>
     </select>
 </div>
```

Comment: @GonçaloLoureiro, didn't my answer solved your issue.

Comment: I already solve with Amit Visodiya answer, but now i need when e select the right model appear other form field with all "Tamanho" available with the selected model...

Comment: @GonçaloLoureiro, I guess I answered first but you didn't commented on my answer for which I couldn't guide you further. If not accept at least you could have upvoted the answer

Comment: @GonçaloLoureiro, I appreciate it. Glad to help you !

Comment: So I  need when e select the right model appear other form field with all "Tamanho" available with the selected model...

Comment: @GonçaloLoureiro, sorry your point is not clear at all. Can you explain more briefly ?

Comment: @GonçaloLoureiro, after accepting the answer why downvote ?

Comment: As you see at my bd http://i.stack.imgur.com/IvpzW.png
I would like to have an form when i select the "modelo" after appear all "tamanho" of that "modelo" after gone appear all "largura" with that "modelo" and "tamanho" and so on...

Comment: @GonçaloLoureiro, sorry I thought you downvoted it instead of upvoting.

Comment: @GonçaloLoureiro, sorry I'm not able to understand your point. Can you explain it with the help of screenshots. Coz I'm not able to understand the way you are explaning

Comment: http://www.mattashapes.com/site/teste/
Check i want when i choose the model apeear below all the sizes of that model

Comment: @GonçaloLoureiro, so you want on change of one dropdown other values should also change, is it so ?

Comment: you'll be needing to use ajax for that, @GonçaloLoureiro

Comment: @GonçaloLoureiro, please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647534/onchange-dynamic-dropdown-values-using-php/35648492#35648492) if it solves your issue

Comment: @GonçaloLoureiro, have checked the link that I mentioned in my previous comment. I have already answered a question related to it

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
//$query ="SELECT modelo,ID FROM volumes"; 
$query = "SELECT Modelo,ID FROM volumes order by ID";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
?>
<div class="form_fields">
    <p>
        <label for="modelo">Model:
            <select name=Modelo>
                <option value=''>Modelo</option>
                <?php
                foreach ($results as $row) {//Array or records stored in $row
                    echo "<option value='{$row->ID}'>{$row->Modelo}</option>";
                    /* Option values are added by looping through the array */
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </label>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Page url is not proper. please check you site this page is available or not ?

Comment: Nice are working! but i have several models it same name can i put for appear only one time each?
http://imgur.com/RorDKoG
Thanks

Comment: we can add DISTINCT with models in query

Comment: $query = "SELECT DISTINCT Modelo,ID FROM volumes order by ID";

Comment: global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT Modelo,ID FROM volumes order by ID";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);

Like this? Not working

Comment: try this query direct in your database and see error

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$query = "SELECT DISTINCT Modelo,ID FROM volumes order by ID"' at line 1

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT Modelo, ID
FROM volumes
ORDER BY ID
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT Modelo,ID FROM volumes order by ID
Only this query

Comment: Appear all the models and not one each

Comment: you can try "SELECT Modelo,ID FROM volumes GROUP BY Modelo order by ID

Comment: Nice its working!
Thanks for all the help!
Only more one thing now i need when e select the right model appear other form field with all "Tamanho" available with the selected model...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

Model:

            Modelo";

            foreach ($wpdb->query($query) as $row) {
                echo "" . $row['Modelo'] . "";

            }

            echo ""; 
            ?>

Comment: I already solve with Amit Visodiya answer, but now i need when e select the right model appear other form field with all "Tamanho" available with the selected model...