# Receiving multiple values back from Ajax using JSON, without JQuery, not working

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm just trying Ajax for the first time, with PHP, and I'd like to avoid using JQuery for now.

I got it to send back 1 list of states wrapped in a drop down element. woo hoo!

Now when I added JSON to return 2 values to be parsed back out (wrapped in an array - one a string, and one am array), it's not working.   I suspect that the data is getting passed around property, but a headers-warning-message is being appended at the front of the return req so the entire string can't properly be parsed. Seems to be just a header issue of some sort.  I'm not familiar with header stuff so I'm not sure where to go next.  I have now pasted that content below.

Main Page:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";

// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($con->connect_error)
  {
  die("Connection failed");
  }

$sql = 'SELECT country_name, country_id
          FROM countrylist
          ORDER BY 1';
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
//Create entry form on page
echo
   "<form action = 'searchresults.php' method='post'>
   <h1>FIND A PET SITTER</h1>
    <br/>

    Enter either a ZipCode

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td style='text-align:right'> 
            Zip Code: &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name='search_zip'></input>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <br/><br/>
    Or Country, City, and State
      <tr>
        <td style='text-align:right'>";
echo "Country:  &nbsp;<td>
<select onChange='getState(this.value)' name='search_country' value=''>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
  {  
    if ($row[country_name] == 'United States of America')
    {
      echo "<option value ='".$row['country_id']."' selected>".$row['country_name']." </option>
      ";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "<option value='".$row['country_id']."'> ".$row['country_name']."</option>
      ";
    }
  }  

echo
      "
      </select>
      </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style='text-align:right'>
            City:  &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name='search_city'>
            </input>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style='text-align:right'>
            <div id='statelab'></div>lab
            </td><td>
            <div id='statediv'></div>div
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
              <input type='submit'>
              </input>
            </form>";


?>

<script>
function getState(countryId) { 
    var strURL="getStates.php?countryIn="+countryId;
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if (req) {
   req.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (req.readyState == 4) {
     // only if "OK"
     if (req.status == 200) {  //if success
        alert(req.responseText);

        var obj = JSON.parse(req.responseText);

        document.getElementById('statediv').innerHTML=obj.stateselectbox;
        document.getElementById('statelab').innerHTML=obj.statelabel;

     } 
     else {
      alert("Problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
     }
    }    
   }   
   req.open("GET", strURL, true);
   req.send(null);
  }  
 }
 getState(230);/*united states*/
 </script>
```

Ajax calls this page:

```
<?php


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";

// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$countryId = intval($_GET["countryIn"]);
if ($countryId < 1 || $countryId > 1000) exit();

$sql = 'SELECT divisions_are_called
          FROM countrieslist
         WHERE country_id = 0'.$countryId ;
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$divisionsAreCalled = $row[divisions_are_called];
//echo $divisionsAreCalled.': &nbsp;</td><td>';

$sql = 'SELECT state_name
          FROM stateslist
         WHERE state_name <> ""
         AND   country_id = 0'.$countryId . '
         ORDER BY 1' ;

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$stateSelectBox = '<select name="statename">';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
$stateSelectBox=$stateSelectBox. '<option value="'.$row["state_name"].'">'.$row["state_name"].'</option>';
  }
$stateSelectBox=$stateSelectBox. '</select>';

$data=array('divisionsarecalled'=>$divisionsAreCalled,
             'stateselectbox'=>$stateSelectBox);
//header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo JSON_encode($data);

?>
```

Here is the response:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/professional/www/dan/myFiles/getStates.php:2) in <b>/home/professional/www/dan/myFiles/getStates.php</b> on line <b>43</b><br />
{"statelabel":"State","stateselectbox":"<select name=\"devices\"><option value=\"Alabama\">Alabama<\/option><option value=\"Alaska\">Alaska<\/option><option value=\"American Samoa\">American Samoa<\/option><option value=\"Arizona\">Arizona<\/option><option value=\"Arkansas\">Arkansas<\/option><option value=\"Armed Forces Americas\">Armed Forces Americas<\/option><option value=\"Armed Forces Europe\">Armed Forces Europe<\/option><option value=\"Armed Forces Pacific\">Armed Forces Pacific<\/option><option value=\"California\">California<\/option><option value=\"Colorado\">Colorado<\/option><option value=\"Connecticut\">Connecticut<\/option><option value=\"Delaware\">Delaware<\/option><option value=\"Florida\">Florida<\/option><option value=\"Georgia\">Georgia<\/option><option value=\"Guam\">Guam<\/option><option value=\"Hawaii\">Hawaii<\/option><option value=\"Idaho\">Idaho<\/option><option value=\"Illinois\">Illinois<\/option><option value=\"Indiana\">Indiana<\/option><option value=\"Iowa\">Iowa<\/option><option value=\"Kansas\">Kansas<\/option><option value=\"Kentucky\">Kentucky<\/option><option value=\"Louisiana\">Louisiana<\/option><option value=\"Maine\">Maine<\/option><option value=\"Maryland\">Maryland<\/option><option value=\"Massachusetts\">Massachusetts<\/option><option value=\"Michigan\">Michigan<\/option><option value=\"Minnesota\">Minnesota<\/option><option value=\"Mississippi\">Mississippi<\/option><option value=\"Missouri\">Missouri<\/option><option value=\"Montana\">Montana<\/option><option value=\"Nebraska\">Nebraska<\/option><option value=\"Nevada\">Nevada<\/option><option value=\"New Hampshire\">New Hampshire<\/option><option value=\"New Jersey\">New Jersey<\/option><option value=\"New Mexico\">New Mexico<\/option><option value=\"New York\">New York<\/option><option value=\"North Carolina\">North Carolina<\/option><option value=\"North Dakota\">North Dakota<\/option><option value=\"Northern Mariana Islands\">Northern Mariana Islands<\/option><option value=\"Ohio\">Ohio<\/option><option value=\"Oklahoma\">Oklahoma<\/option><option value=\"Oregon\">Oregon<\/option><option value=\"Pennsylvania\">Pennsylvania<\/option><option value=\"Puerto Rico\">Puerto Rico<\/option><option value=\"Rhode Island\">Rhode Island<\/option><option value=\"South Carolina\">South Carolina<\/option><option value=\"South Dakota\">South Dakota<\/option><option value=\"Tennessee\">Tennessee<\/option><option value=\"Texas\">Texas<\/option><option value=\"U.S. Virgin Islands\">U.S. Virgin Islands<\/option><option value=\"Utah\">Utah<\/option><option value=\"Vermont\">Vermont<\/option><option value=\"Virginia\">Virginia<\/option><option value=\"Washington\">Washington<\/option><option value=\"Washington DC\">Washington DC<\/option><option value=\"West Virginia\">West Virginia<\/option><option value=\"Wisconsin\">Wisconsin<\/option><option value=\"Wyoming\">Wyoming<\/option><\/select>"}
```

---

EDIT:  I added changed these 3 lines in the page ajax calls and it works now:

---

```
<?php
ob_start(); //<--ADDED THIS
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xx ...


...$data=array('statelabel'=>$divisionsAreCalled,
             'stateselectbox'=>$stateSelectBox);
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');

//echo json_encode($data);  //<--CHANGED THIS TO THE 2 LINES BELOW

ob_end_clean(); // this clears any potential unwanted output
exit(json_encode($data));
?>
```

Comment: The only that is to be done is : get country id value on the next page by `$_GET['countryId']` and then write query related to that

Comment: Y, you can check my answer that I answered in a similar question and it is what you require here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647534/onchange-dynamic-dropdown-values-using-php/35648492#35648492

Comment: It looks like your ajax is only returning one value?

Comment: You are also sending one value only I guess. What else you want to be done and How many values you want to return

Comment: I would like to be able to parse my 2 JSON encoded elements back out in the main program so that I can print both of them.

Comment: I think the problem is that it's sending the data back, but there is a header warning appended to the  beginning of the req that messes everything up when I run JSON.parse on it?  I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of this error.

Comment: please post that error as well, @Dan Y.

Comment: "Header already sent" is caused by your PHP file. Somewhere on there, you have a `header(xxx)` that conflicts with the existing header information. It looks like it is not a JS problem.

Comment: I stripped out everything I could find that relates to header in both files, but I'm still getting the same issue.  Are there other thing I can do to manage the headers?

Comment: The error message precisely tells you where the error happens (line 43, probably your `header('Content-Type: application/javascript');`) and where you previously output data (line 2). So it's this "line 2" that is the cause of the error. If this doesnt help you to figure out what is the problem, edit your question to show us the _entire_ `getStates.php` file.

Comment: I added the entire code as requested.  Then I just got it running by adding this to the php file called by ajax: At the beginning I added ob_start(); and at the end ob_end_clean(); and exit(json_encode($data)) instead of the echo statement. Thanks all for helping me determine it was a header problem!

Comment: Looking at your entire code, it's immediately clear: you had several blank lines (from line 2, as notified by the error message). Note that a good practice is to _never_ let any blank line in your PHP code (when they are here for clarity purpose, you can replace them by an empty _comment_ line): this way you are always quiet. And this way you don't need `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()`!

Comment: Ok, I will mark that down.  Thanks much!